# Dynamic Validation List - Multiple Criteria

Tags: list, excel, validation, excel-formula, vba

I want to create a data validation list that changes in size depending on 2 criteria. The sheet looks like this:

```
A    |    B    |    C
1    |    1    |  100
2    |    0    |  200
3    |    1    |  300
4    |    1    |  400
5    |    0    |  500
6    |    1 
7    |    1
```

Column A is the reference number of a loan
Column B is an activation cell (1 = loan is activated, 0 = loan is not activated) 
Column C is the loan amount

I want to create a validation list that shows the reference number of the loans that are activated (i.e. Column B = 1) AND that have a value in Column C (i.e. Column C is not blank).

I managed to create the validation list that adjusts itself for the blank cells, but I don't know how to account for Column B as a second criteria.

A VBA code to do this would also be helpful!

Comment: Can you be more specific as what exactly you need to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

A simple formula in Column D copied to all cells below with show you a validated column with TRUE beside the valid rows

```
=IF(B2,IF(C2,TRUE,""),"")
```

looks like

[image]